# Require js not loading jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs

I am a newbie to require js and faced this strange problem while creating our first :

Following is the home page :`index.html`

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My first JS app using require</title>
</head>
<body>
    <strong> This is my first require js app</strong>
    <span id="output"></span>
</body>
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
</html>
```

`main.js` is as follows :

```
require(['lib/jquery','app/message'],function($,message){
        $('#output').html(message);
    });
```

`message.js` is as follows :

```
define(function(){
    return "Message from message.js";
});
```

When i run index.html on browser, $ in main.js comes as undefined. It does not produce any other error on console. Also all files are loaded successfully(confirmed from networks tab in browser).

If i change the main.js to be as follows :

```
require(['jquery','app/message'],function($,message){
        $('#output').html(message);
    });
```

And accordingly place jquery.js in appropriate directory, everything works fine.

I am not able to figure out the reason here. Can anybody please help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide the require.config code

Comment: @VladuIonut I did not write any require.config. I did not find a need as it is my first page using require.js. I have directly used the paths in my js files.